# Multiple variable query find mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, bottle

I need to know how can I do a find query in mongodb if dont know exactly how many parameter have the query.

Example:

```py
@get('/find_users')
def find_users():

# The posibilities are
# http://localhost:8080find_users?name=Andrew         
# http://localhost:8080/find_users?name=Andrew&surname=Sun

db = mongoClient['bdname']
coleccion = db['users']
dicc = request.query.decode()

username = ""
firstsurname = ""

for item in dicc:    
    if item == "name":
        username = request.query.name
    elif item == "surname":
        firstsurname = request.query.surname

d = coleccion.find({'name':username, 'surname':username})

for item in d:
    print(item['name'])
    print(item['surname'])
```

With this query if I only find the user by name, the surname take a string empty and the results doesnt correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [ExpressJS docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query):

> `request.query` is an object containing a property for each query string parameter in the route.

So, in other words, you don't have to decode `request.query`.

When you make a request to `http://localhost:8080find_users?name=Andrew`, your `request.query` object will be `{"name":"Andrew"}`.

When you make a request to `http://localhost:8080find_users?name=Andrew&surname=Sun`, then your `request.query` object will be `{"name":"Andrew", "surname": "Sun"}`.

Properties on the query object are mapped to query string parameters from the request url. You don't have to know exactly how many parameters are in the query. When the query string parameters change, the query object properties change. You may use this object to perform the database search:

```js
var findOptions = request.query;

collection.find(findOptions);
```

This way, you won't have the problem with the surname taking an empty string and messing up the results. If `surname` is not part of the query string parameters, then the object will not contain a `surname` property, and the database search will ignore this field during the search.